# How to prove type equality over an implicit?

Tags: scala, types

I have tried to create a minimal example, `x` doesn't compile in the code below:

```
sealed trait Foo

case object FooOne extends Foo

sealed trait Bar[T] {
  type foo <: Foo
}

object Bar {
  implicit case object BarOne extends Bar[Int] {
    type foo = FooOne.type
  }
}

case class Quk[B: Bar](b: B)

sealed trait Baz[F <: Foo]

case object BazOne extends Baz[FooOne.type]

case class Bat[B: Bar, F <: Foo](r: Quk[B], z: Baz[F])(implicit ev: Bar[B]#foo =:= F)

object Bat {
  val x = Bat(Quk(1), BazOne)  // Compilation error here!
}
```

The error I'm getting (in eclipse) is:

```
Cannot prove that com.muhuk.Example.Bar[Int]#foo =:= com.muhuk.Example.FooOne.type.
not enough arguments for method apply: (implicit evidence$2: com.muhuk.Example.Bar[Int], implicit ev: =:=[com.muhuk.Example.Bar[Int]#foo,com.muhuk.Example.FooOne.type])com.muhuk.Example.Bat[Int,com.muhuk.Example.FooOne.type] in object Bat. Unspecified value parameter ev.
```

`Foo` doesn't depend on anything. `Bar` & `Baz` depend on `Foo` but they don't know about each other, except in the context of `Bat`.

How can I get `Bat`'s constructor to ensure its `Quk` parameter and `Baz` parameter have both the same `Foo` type?

I am using Scala 2.11.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Aux` type alias trick for `Bar` and its dependant type `foo` :

```
object Bar {
  type Aux[T, F] = Bar[T] { type foo = F }

  // BarOne ...
}
```

Now you can define `Bat` as follows :

```
case class Bat[B, F <: Foo](r: Quk[B], z: Baz[F])(implicit bar: Bar.Aux[B, F])
```

Your example now compiles :

```
val x = Bat(Quk(1), BazOne)
// x: Bat[Int,FooOne.type] = Bat(Quk(1),BazOne)
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more. Here is a more detailed explanation: http://gigiigig.github.io/posts/2015/09/13/aux-pattern.html